# LC-3: How to Save A String to a Different Register?

Tags: string, assembly, lc3

I have a question regarding strings in LC-3. For instance, I can write code saving a string in R0 and everything works. However, when I change the register, either nothing or total gibberish is printed to the console.

For instance, if I put this code into the simulator:

```
    .ORIG x3000
    LEA R3, L1

L1  .STRINGZ "Hello World"
    TRAP x22
    TRAP x25
    .END
```

I get in return: ----Halting the processor----
How do I get it to print "Hello World" with the string saved in R3?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have your string in the middle of your instructions, where the string bytes will be executed as instruction bytes.  But re: your question, the TRAP interface uses fixed registers.  Use a `mov` instruction to copy the pointer to a different register before or after using TRAP, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the predefined TRAP instructions in LC-3 (except for HALT) will use R0. TRAP x22 (PUTS) will print a string in R0.

If you need to move a value in one register to another the lc-3 doesn't have a mov instruction specifically instead you can do this with either the ADD or AND instructions there are three ways of doing so.

ADD RX, RY, 0

AND RX, RY, RY

AND RX, RY, -1

where RX and RY are R0-R7.